# R, "%>%" symbol overlapping error, "[[x]] only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"

Tags: r

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04

KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0

Qt Version: 5.12.8

Kernel Version: 5.8.0-38-generic

OS Type: 64-bit

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

I made a toy case for my error.

```
library(dplyr) #version 1.0.2
library(leaflet) #version ‘2.0.4.1’
library(tidyverse) #version ‘1.3.0’
library(sets) #version ‘1.0.18’
haha <- data.frame(country = c("USA", "Albania", "Turkey", "China", "Sudan"),
                   democracy_score = c(19, 16, 16, 5, 10))
haha<-haha %>% filter(country=="USA")
```

It reports the overlapping of the operator "%>%".

```
Attaching package: ‘sets’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    singleton

The following object is masked from ‘package:forcats’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:stringr’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:tidyr’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:tibble’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:leaflet’:

    %>%

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    %>%
```

When running, the error is reported.

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

However, if we execute `detach("package:sets", unload=TRUE)`and delete the line 'library(sets)' (simply unload the package "sets" and exclude that package), everything gets normal now. Is it possible to specify the package of the operator "%>%"?

Comment: Look at the exclude= argument of the library function.

Comment: ??? What do you mean? Could not find "exclude argument" in dplyr::filter() function.

Comment: My comment refers to the library function, not the filter function,.  `?library`